# Transforming xml files in PowerShell, with parameter

Tags: xml, powershell, xslt

I am doing an XML transform with XSLT in PowerShell.
There are two XML files involved, one containing the structure and the other containing texts in different languages. The file containing a structure is given directly as an argument to the transform method, whereas the other file has been a variable in the xsl file. It all worked fine in one language, but when I added all the languages, I found out that I had a path hard coded in the xsl file.

So, I needed to adapt my xsl file and the PowerShell transformation to have the text files in different languages as a parameter. I found out there was this `System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList` that sounded promising. But I am not able to figure out how the transform method could work with three arguments and how it could work with my xsl file. Now PowerShell says that I have an issue with overload (so this is not just cognitive overload). I could really use some help with this.

`Cannot find an overload for "Transform" and the argument count: "3".`

And what do I need to do in my xsl file to be able to use the parameter instead of the variable?

A snippet of my PowerShell script:

```
            $XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1

            $argList = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList

            $Xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
            $PathToXsltFile = "$pwd\xsl\lookup_texts.xsl"
            $Xslt.Load($PathToXsltFile,$XsltSettings,$(New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver))

            $PathOfXMLRulesTextsFile = Join-Path -Path $langdestination -ChildPath ('{0}{1}' -f $topic.name, 'Texts.xml')
            Write-Host $PathOfXMLRulesTextsFile

            $argList.AddParam("textFile", "", $topicTextsOutputFile)
            $Xslt.Transform($topicRulesFile, $argList, $PathOfXMLRulesTextsFile)
```

A snippet of my XSL file (I am doing more lookups):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:zzz="urn:cfgtext" exclude-result-prefixes="zzz">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="input:textFile" />
<!-- 
<xsl:variable name="textFile" select="'C:\Rules\CFG_Texts.xml'"/>
-->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@resourceID">
    <xsl:variable name="messageNumber" select="."/>
    <xsl:attribute name="resourceID">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="resourceText">
        <xsl:value-of select="document($textFile)/zzz:Resources/zzz:Text[@resourceID=$messageNumber]/node()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: There are no overloads to take the input and output file name or path and the argument list, you will have to use some overload like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xsltransform.transform?view=net-7.0#system-xml-xsl-xsltransform-transform(system-xml-xpath-ixpathnavigable-system-xml-xsl-xsltargumentlist-system-io-stream) where e.g. you pass in a `System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument` into which you `Load` your input document as the first argument, your argument list as the second and an Stream e.g. `File.OpenWrite(resultFileNameOrPath)` as the third.

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable clue. I have a working solution now. I will post it here also, for the record.

Answer (score 0):

I used a file stream as input to the `Transform` method, as Martin Honnen suggested:

```
$XsltSettings = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltSettings
$XsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = 1

$argList = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XsltArgumentList

$Xslt = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$PathToXsltFile = "$pwd\xsl\lookup_texts.xsl"
$Xslt.Load($PathToXsltFile,$XsltSettings,$(New-Object System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver))

$PathOfXMLRulesTextsFile = Join-Path -Path $langdestination -ChildPath ('{0}{1}' -f $topic.name, 'Texts.xml')
Write-Host $PathOfXMLRulesTextsFile

$argList.AddParam("textFile", "", $topicTextsOutputFile)

$fs = New-Object IO.FileStream $PathOfXMLRulesTextsFile, ([System.IO.FileMode]::Create)
Try
{
    $Xslt.Transform($topicRulesFile, $argList, $fs)
}
Finally
{
    $fs.Dispose()
}
```

Also the xsl file was adjusted.
`<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` could not be used for input documents that have already been loaded, so I removed it. I also had my param prefixed, which I also removed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:zzz="urn:cfgtext" exclude-result-prefixes="zzz">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="textFile" />
<!-- 
<xsl:variable name="textFile" select="'C:\Rules\CFG_Texts.xml'"/>
-->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@resourceID">
    <xsl:variable name="messageNumber" select="."/>
    <xsl:attribute name="resourceID">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="resourceText">
        <xsl:value-of select="document($textFile)/zzz:Resources/zzz:Text[@resourceID=$messageNumber]/node()"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```